# Ansible Dynamic inventory getting permission denied issue, while able to connect using ssh

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, devops

1. Created an ansible aws connection.
2. Provisioned single ec2 instance
3. Trying to ping that instance using ansible dynamic inventory.
4. getting the following issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze6r3.png)

Comment: One piece of advice: try adding code samples, console output, issued commands etc. in the body of the question rather than posting links to a png image. It would make it available at hand and much easier to search through. You can select such plaintext output and press **Ctrl** + **k** to nicely format your code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume connection with EC2 is by using user and public key.
Now, since you have not specified details regarding how dynamic inventory is configured, I assume it is ec2.py and ec2.ini files.

If you are doing simple ping (as shown in attached image), you will need to provide user name and key file path as below :

```
ansible -i ec2.py -m ping -u "ec2-user" --key-file "<path to the .pem file on this host>"
```

and as mentioned in comments,try to provide code snippets and/or details when posting question. This helps everyone understand question/use case better and can be answered better, without taking any assumptions.